# Converting hexadecimal to decimal using dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

**Basically:**

I am trying to convert hex to decimal using dictionaries but I can't figure out how I would convert it. I have tried using a for loop to iterate over the hexadecimal value that the user enters, and to convert each one by multiplying it to a power of 16 depending on the length of hex. For example, if the user enters F21, the program should recognise that the length is 3 so should start by multiplying 15(F) by 16^2 and add this to 2*16^1 and add this to 1*16^0. But I come across so many errors

**Hexadecimal to Decimal Dictionary:**

```
hex_to_decimal = {
    "0":"0",
    "1":"1",
    "2":"2",
    "3":"3",
    "4":"4",
    "5":"5",
    "6":"6",
    "7":"7",
    "8":"8",
    "9":"9",
    "A":"10",
    "B":"11",
    "C":"12",
    "D":"13",
    "E":"14",
    "F":"15"
}
```

**Note:**

I am not trying to use this solution as I am trying to practice dictionaries

```
s = "F21"
i = int(s, 16)
```

Comment: "But I come across so many errors" what errors? you need to show us what you've tried and specifically what's going wrong if we are going to be able to help.

Comment: Aaron The solution was spaghetti code and I don't want to improve it, but would like an alternative efficient way of completing this task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are converting to decimals, the default base for integers, you should make the values of `hex_to_demical` integers rather than strings, so that you can perform numeric operations on each translated hex number:

```
hex_to_decimal = {
    "0": 0,
    "1": 1,
    "2": 2,
    "3": 3,
    "4": 4,
    "5": 5,
    "6": 6,
    "7": 7,
    "8": 8,
    "9": 9,
    "A": 10,
    "B": 11,
    "C": 12,
    "D": 13,
    "E": 14,
    "F": 15
}
def convert(s):
    i = 0
    for h in s:
        i = i *16 + hex_to_decimal[h]
    return i
```

with the above code,

```
convert('F21')
```

would return:

```
3873
```

Comment: Thanks, except it would be `i = i *16 + int(hex_to_decimal[h])`

Comment: You're welcome. Like I mentioned, you don't need the `int` conversion if you initialize your `hex_to_decimal` with integers rather than strings.

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner, using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
def conv(s):
    return sum(16**i*int(hex_to_decimal[x]) for i, x in enumerate(s[::-1]))

conv('FF')
# 255
conv('A1')
# 161
conv('F21')
# 3873
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply look over both the index `i` and the digit `n` of the hex string using `enumerate()`, and do the computation `n_dec*16**i` (e.g. with `n_dec = 15` when `n = F`). Specifically, we have `n_dec = int(hex_to_decimal[n])`, with the `int()` needed because you store the values of your `dict` as `str`s. Finally, `sum` everything up:

```
s_hex = "F21"
s_dec = str(sum(
    int(hex_to_decimal[n])*16**i for i, n in enumerate(reversed(s_hex))
))
```

The `reversed()` is needed because the first (hexadecimal) digits refer to the larger values.
The `str()` is used just to keep the final decimal result as a `str`, just as the values in your `dict`.